# Are there any drawbacks to using a nested class instead of declaring a new one?

Tags: java, object-oriented, programming-practices, code-reviews

I'm doing code review on a change my co-worker made to our Java application, and I've found something I'm not very familiar with - a nested class.

From reviewing the code, it seems like the nested class is being used as if it were a normal class - and asking my co-worker about it, the reason for putting it in as a nested class is because of a source control issue preventing her from creating a new class on the day she coded it.

Now this is bothering me - because while there's no reason to introduce this element into our code (very few classes use nested classes in our application), there's also no drawbacks to it that I can think of either.  The nested class is, in a very loose way, related to the class it came from, and re-writing the code so that the nested class is an independent one would take some time.

Is there any good reason to have my co-worker redo the code so that this nested class is independent?  Or would I just be asking them to waste their time on something that does not matter?

Note that there does not appear to be any functional affect on implementing the class this way - so any argument would have to be from best practice or bad structure, rather than trying to prove that it doesn't work (because it does work - I'm just not sure it's appropriate).

Comment: `Are there any drawbacks to using a nested class instead of declaring a new one?` -- Yes; you can't use it anywhere else.  In practice, nested classes should be a very rare occurrence; they are an indicator that the containing class is already too complicated.

Comment: Is the nested class marked as private?

Comment: @DavidArno No not at all - which to me indicated that there's really no need to use it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I would agree with you - but the original class was actually very simple.

Comment: @NickAlexeev This definitely made me turn my head significantly - so I'm inclined to put this on the 'bad code' side of things.  Especially since it's something we'd have to explain to someone further down the line if they need to fix it.

Comment: **Voting to close.** If this question were focused on the pros and cons of a nested class in general, it would be more objectively answerable. As written, you're effectively asking us to mediate in a code review (generally out of scope here). And worse, you're asking us to do so without any relevant context other than, "My coworker did this because " *<a reason that doesn't actually make sense>* ... **Why aren't you discussing this with your coworker and/or the rest of the team???**

Comment: To preempt the more general question: **Use nested classes when nothing else should be able to (or need to) instantiate it. Otherwise, create a public class.** ... If you have other internal reasons that impede creating public classes, discuss those reasons as a team ... Or submit another question specifically around those impediments and how to overcome them *or whatever.*

Comment: @svidgen I don't think I can re-word this as such a question - though I probably should have asked it as such from the start.  Really, I was trying to answer two questions at once - what are the practical purposes of Nested Classes, and should an unnecessary nested class fail a code review.  I'm not sure if the latter would be appropriate though - but I should have started at least with the former.

Comment: @Zibbobz, Too many folk here with "vote to close" powers never bother to read the wording for opinion-based questions, which states "*Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.*". They just vote to close as opinion-based without bothering to read the answers or because they personally disagree with the answers. This is often the case, like here, where the answers agree and they don't like it. Sad, but that's life.

Comment: @svidgen, "*If this question were focused on the pros and cons of a nested class in general, it would be more objectively answerable*". No. such a question would be 100% off-topic. We do not do pros and cons questions here. Your vote to close is completely misguided.

Comment: @DavidArno Likewise, too many folk here are too eager to slurp up reputation gains with misleading answers to questions that are almost completely devoid of context or objectivity. (And that's just dishonest and unhelpful, IMO.) Maybe a "pro/con" question isn't strictly on-topic either. But, a pro/con question isn't more than a word-choice or two away from being a "Why would I want to do X?" question -- which is completely on-topic here. (Despite being a thinly veiled pro/con question.)

Comment: @DavidArno Sooo ... to the contrary, I'd suggest that *you providing an answer to a question you have almost zero context on* is "completely misguided." Though, I'd much rather we didn't condescend to each other when we disagree ... in the future, I mean. I'm happy to return some condescension on this one! (Because it felt like you were being a bit of a jerk, honestly.)

Comment: @Zibbobz That's fine. The VTC doesn't nullify the answers you've already received. And, being a bit biased perhaps, I think the one-liner-ish answer I gave in my 2nd comment is all you need to take back to your team for an *internal* discussion. A VTC is **often** just a statement that, "some of the more frequent users here advise you to read answers to this question with a grain of salt... "

Comment: Nowadays, you can extract a nested class using an IDE refactoring capabilities. So it is not so much work to do. I think anything that's surprising for no good reason should fail a review. And I think nested classes are surprising.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the nested class is private then it is part of the implementation details of that class. There are various valid reasons why such a class might exist: data encapsulation, proving a private implementation of an interface to name two.

If the class is accessible outside of its containing class, then the single responsibility principle likely comes into play. Is that inner class genuinely a responsibility of the outer one? Since you say it’s only loosely related, then the answer is likely, no.

Nesting classes tightly couples them. It makes the outer class more complex as it now contains two class’s worth of functionality. And that outer class now has two responsibilities. And all this exists because of a problem with a check-in.

So I’d definitely recommend restructuring the code in this case too move that inner class out into its own file where it belongs.

Answer (score 2):

Given that it was only created due to a problem with source control rarther than any design considerations then yes. You should probably refactor it.

However, if the code is functional and you don't have a "no nested classes" coding style rule then I would not recommend you fail the code review because of it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm obligated to post this cartoon about the measure of code quality.

[image: this cartoon about the measure of code quality]

If the only reason for creating the nested class instead of a free-standing class was a clerical restriction [source control is an automated clerk], then the nested class should be refactored into a free-standing class. If there are no other reasons, this should be an easy refactoring.

Comment: Yeah. If the answer to "Why is this a nested class?" is "Because source control wouldn't allow me to create a new file" then it definitely garners one or two WTF's. And maybe an AYFKM!? ... and maybe a link to Let Me Google That For You with the search terms "how to use `<Source Control X>`"

Comment: Sarcasm aside, this is a teaching opportunity. Teach the coder to reach out for help in situations like this, so you don't fail a code review for such a silly reason.